# Diffable Data Source - Reload Header

Tags: ios, swift, diffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

What are the ways in which a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` header can be reloaded?

I have a collection view with a header that displays user details, and rows that display posts, the model is

```
struct PostUser {
    var user: User
    var post: Post
}
```

when I change a property via the snapshot

```
    var postUsers = [PostUser]() {
        didSet {
            self.applySnapshot(postUsers)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func applySnapshot(_ postsUser: [PostUser]) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, PostUser>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(postsUser)
        self.datasource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
```

the rows reload, however the supplementary header does not.  The only way I can get the header to change is if I make the Section part of the model, so:

```
    struct Section: Hashable {
        var User: User
    }
```

my apply snapshot now becomes

```
    fileprivate func applySnapshot(_ postsUser: [PostUser]) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, PostUser>()
        snapshot.appendSections([Section(User: self.user)])
        snapshot.appendItems(postsUser)
        self.datasource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
```

I then set the user separately

```
    var user: User! = nil {
        didSet {
            self.applySnapshot(self.postUsers)
        }
    }
```

and the header reloads.

I don't quite understand why when I change something in postUsers, the rows reload, but the header does not - until I implement a model as part of the section?

I do understand that diffable works on hashing, and so when I change a property, the table reloads, but it feels like the header should also reload, but it is treated separately?

Answer (score 5):

Headers are only reloaded when a change in the section itself is detected. If only the items change, the supplementary views will remain unchanged. Another thing you could look into depending on your case would be to set `animatingDifferences` to `false` when you want to reload a header since, as of the latest iOS 14 beta, that will trigger `reloadData`. No diffing will be done.

Comment: On iOS 15, this advice should change to calling applySnapshotUsingReloadData instead

Comment: Yes, iOS 15 introduces lots of improvements around reloading and diffing now always happens no matter the animations so definitely disregard my answer if you're targeting iOS 15+

Answer (score 1):

I figure out to use `reloadSections` for iOS 15 previous is workable.

```swift
private func applyNewSnapshot() {
    var newSnapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        self.dataSource.applySnapshotUsingReloadData(newSnapshot)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        newSnapshot.reloadSections([.main])
        self.dataSource.apply(newSnapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```